# KNN error：‘train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r

I hope to run KNN with the following two data frame. The following is the information of the data(already been scaled). `age` and `lr_scale` would be the features and `euRefVoteAfter` is the outcome variable.

```
     head(training)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      age lr_scale         euRefVoteAfter
    <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl+lbl>
1 -1.20     -0.808 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
2  1.25     -1.29  1 [Stay out of the EU]
3  0.636     0.886 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
4  0.0245   -0.324 1 [Stay out of the EU]
5 -1.26      0.402 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
6 -0.770     0.402 0 [Rejoin the EU]     


> head(testing)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      age lr_scale         euRefVoteAfter
    <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl+lbl>
1 -1.20     -0.808 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
2  1.25     -1.29  1 [Stay out of the EU]
3  0.636     0.886 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
4  0.0245   -0.324 1 [Stay out of the EU]
5 -1.26      0.402 0 [Rejoin the EU]     
6 -0.770     0.402 0 [Rejoin the EU]
```

And i run the following codes:

```
y_pred <- knn(train = training[, -3],
              test = testing[, -3],
              cl = training[,3],
              k = 3,
              prob = FALSE)
```

And i got the message`'train' and 'class' have different lengths`.
I've found some solution to fix this error, and try again as follow:

```
v1=training[,3]
y_pred <- knn(train = training[, -3],
              test = testing[, -3],
              cl = v1,
              k = 3,
              prob = FALSE)
```

But the same error message occured.
I'm sure the length of the variables are the same

```
> length(training$euRefVoteAfter)
[1] 26026
> length(training$age)
[1] 26026
> length(training$lr_scale)
[1] 26026
```

If someone can help me with this problem, I'd be really appreciated.

Comment: It is a bit suspicious that your training and testing data (as displayed) are identical.

Comment: @G5W thanks for pointing out that, I didn't realize.  What I have done is just splitting one data frame into two with `split <- sample.split(bes2$euRefVoteAfter,SplitRatio = 0.75)   training <- subset(bes2, split=T,na.rm=T)   testing <- subset(bes2,split=F,na.rm=T)`